# How do you ensure address form autofills correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, user-experience, form-for

I have a form in Rails, part of which asks for an address:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :postal_address do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :apartment_number %>
    <%= ff.text_field :building_name %>
    <%= ff.text_field :building_number %>
    <%= ff.text_field :street %>
    <%= ff.text_field :town %>
    <%= ff.text_field :postcode %>
  <% end %>
```

However, when I click the little autofill thing in Safari (below) the form is filled in incorrectly.

[image: autofill thing]

This is obviously wrong:

[image]

Is there any way I can instruct the browser to autofill the fields with the expected data? Or is it solely up to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work better if you add `autocomplete` attribute to inputs. Browser tries to guess about field's purpose from its name, but not sure if it knows "Building number" and "Town"

```
<%= ff.text_field :town, autocomplete: 'address-level2' %> # 'city' should work too
```

You can check list of available values in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)